# sequelize how to refer to instance in Model.update

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to refer to other properties on an instance in Model.update? For example, if I have a Person model; would the following be possible:

```
Person.update(
  { fullName: instance.firstName + ' ' + instance.lastName }, /* this is where I want to access the instance */
  { where: { fullName: null }}
);
```

What's the correct way to do this if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it can't be done through a Model. However you can do it if you run a SQL statement directly, which Sequelize does support:

```
sequelize.query(`
 UPDATE person SET "fullName"="firstName" || ' ' || "lastName" 
 where "fullName" is null
`);
```

(Assuming you're using a Postgres database, you may need to adjust your table/column escaping/names depending on case. If they are all lower they don't need the quotes, but if they have any upper casing, they probably need to be quoted. One of the few things I don't like about Postgres)

Comment: Thanks David! I figured that may be the case - ie that instances aren’t actually returned here. I just used a simple example to illustrate the question. What I need to do is pretty complex and doesn’t translate so straightforwardly to SQL. I’ll find a workaround though!